# Unable to resolve this Compilation Error in Flex builder 3

Tags: flex3, flexbuilder

I am new Web App development using Flex Builder 3 and currently I am facing the following problem:

Attached is a code snippet from the mxml file:

```
 <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
     import com.bx.Char10;
     import com.bx.A;
            [Bindable] private var inputParam:A = new A()       
            inputParam.CustNumber.char10 = '0123456789'

        }
     ]]>

  </mx:Script>
```

This Gives a compile error
1120 Access of undefined property inputParam

However if I replace

```
inputParam.CustNumber.char10 = '0123456789'
```

with

```
  private function set():void
    {
     inputParam.CustNumber.char10 = '0123456789'
    }
```

The compile error goes away.

My Question is :
How can I remove this Compilation Error without using the workaround I did?

Comment: You can start by **not shouting at us** :-)

Comment: done..shouting removed..Now its more like a SOS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I don't believe that one can execute arbitrary statements directly inside a class body.  (The "Script" tag's contents are treated as if they were directly inside the class body).

Only function definitions or variable property definitions are allowed.

A different work-around to use is to pass the information through the constructor of the variable property you're interested in.

```
[Bindable] private var inputParam:A = new A('0123456789')
```